# What are the references from Puranas regarding the life span of Lord Rama?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, krishna, ramayana, rama

Lord Rama is said to be of Treta of 24th chaturyuga while current is 28th. Some references to support this are:

> Treta yuge chaturvinshe ravane tapseh shakshyat | Ram dashrtathi
> prapiye sagane shakyamiyeewan ||  [Vayu Puraan 70.88]
>
> Chaturvinshe yuge chapi vishwamitra pure sare | Loke ram iti khyate tejsah
> bhaskaropam ||  [Harivansh 22.104]
>
> Chaturvinshe yuge vats tretayaam raghuvanshaje | Ramo naam bhavishyami
> chaturvhayu sanatane || [Brahmand Puraan 2.2.36.30]

All of the above references are stating "Treta Yuge Chaturvinshe" i.e., Rama was in Treta of 24th Chaturyuga . Mahabharata is of 28th Dwapara and this is now 28th Kaliyuga. But the exact lifespan of Rama is not mentioned unlike Krishna who left earth for his abode at the age of [126years](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Lord-Krishna-lived-for-125-years/articleshow/844211.cms), even though indirect reference are made.

> [Srimad Bhagvatam: Chapter 11, Canto 9](http://bhagavata.org/canto9/chapter11.html) 11.18 After she went to
> heaven the Lord observed strict celibacy and performed a ceremony, an
> Agnihotra [fire] sacrifice, that was
> **continued for thirteen thousand years** without interruption.

[Sarga 128, Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War, Valmiki Ramayana](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga128/yuddha_128_frame.htm)

> 96 Having enjoyed the **kingship for ten thousand years**, Rama performed
> a hundred horse-sacrifices, in which good horses were sacrificed and
> numerous gifts bestowed.
>
> 106 All the people were endowed with excellent characteristics. All
> were engaged in virtue. Rama was engaged in the **kingship thus for one
> thousand years.**

So, the question is about any other numerical references from other Puranas regarding life span of Lord Rama or periods of events occurred in his life time?

Comment: I think those are translation errors.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Padma Purana,](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana27.html) after the departure of Sita in the Earth, Sri Rama ruled the Kingdom for 11,000 years.

> After Sita’s disappearance, Shri Rama ruled for eleven thousand years.

So if we add up the number years he spent on Earth, before the departure of Sita, we will get his life span.

1. By the time he reached Chitrakuta, at the commencement of 14 years of exile period - 25 years ([10th sloka of 47th Sarga of Aranya Kanda)](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga47/aranya_47_frame.htm)
2. Years spent in exile period - 14 years
3. Period elapsed between his ascension to kingdom to the fight between him and his sons - 20 years (approx)

So, Sri Rama must have lived, according to Padma Purana, 11,059 (approx) years.