# Ramayana ( Genealogy of Shri Ram )

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, rama, suryavansh

Vedas tell that human can live upto 100 years with a maximum of 400 years .

So if we still assume that Ramayana happened again in current chaturyuga ( 28 th treta yuga )

Dwapara Yuga which is of 8,64,000 years .

Given below is Shri Ram Genealogy after him

82. Kusha
83. Atithi
84. Nishadha
85. Nala
86. Nabhas
87. Pundarika
88. Kshemadhanvan
89. Devanika
90. Ahinagu
91. Roop
92. Rooroo
93. Paripatra
94. Dala (or Balasthala)
95. Chhal (or Anal)
96. Ukya
97. Vajranabha
98. Khagan (or Shankhanaad)
99. Vighruti (or Vyushitashva)
100. Vishvasaha-2
101. Hiranyanabha
102. Pushya
103. Dhruvasandhi
104. Sudarshana-2
105. Agnivatna-2
106. Shighra
107. Maru-2
108. Prasushruta
109. Susandhi (or Sugandhi)
110. Amarshana and Sahasvanta, the sons of Susandhi
111. Mahasvan
112. Vishwasahav
113. Prasenjit-1
114. Takshaka
115. Brihadbala ( Abhimanyu killed Brihadbala at age 125 years in Mahabharata War).

If we divide 8,64,000 from 33 Kings after Shri Ram we get 26,181 years.

So how come Kings were able to maintain average of 26000 years of lifespan when vedas says lifespan of maximum 400 years ??

Please tell with reference.

Comment: Vedas dont discuss Yugas or kings lineage, only Puranas do. Some Puranas like Srimad Bhagavatam mention lifespan of Rama to be over 10,000 years in Treta. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/what-are-the-references-from-puranas-regarding-the-life-span-of-lord-rama while age in Satyuga of 1lakh years.

Comment: Rama rajya lasted for 11000 years. Dasharatha lived for 60,000. In previous yugas lifespan was much longer.

Comment: But vedas say humans can't live more than 400 years @ram

Comment: @RanaPriyanshuSinh, do vedas specify in which yuga they can't ?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The link you provided is good but still I am not satisfied.  V

Comment: @Ram I am assuming that Vedas were given to humans when brahma ji created humans . Humans were created in Satya Yuga . So vedas were given to humans in Satya yuga.  So why will vedas give lifespan of Kaliyuga to people living in Satya yuga

Comment: @RanaPriyanshuSinh, Vedas were given to Brahma when Vishnu created Brahma. What i meant was - do Vedas say that humans cannot live for more than 400 years in ALL yugas ?

Comment: No vedas didn't say like that. But then please clarify my 1 doubt Ravana killed Anaranya , a very old DESCENDANT of Shri Ram . That means Ravan was very old in Ram - Ravan War but why didn't ravan have his grandchildren and great grandchildrens. Same in the case of Shri Ram he ruled Ayodhya for 11000 yrs but still he didn't have grandchildren and great grandchildren when he was in earth before Ram ji sacrificed his earthly body. Please answer me it's a genuine doubt.  Now pls don't tell me they used to marry late because Maa Sita married at age 18.

Comment: @RanaPriyanshuSinh, not all people have sons and grandsons at same age. You can have son at age 20, or age 60. and your son could have a son at age 20 or 60. so there could be 40 years gap between grandfather and grandson, or 120 years gap. Now imagine if you can have a son at either age 20, or 60, or 10000. There is lot of time so no hurry to have son/grandson/grand-grandson etc.

Comment: @Ram ek doubt aur clear kar dijiye. In mahabharat war it is believed that Yudhisthir's age was 91 years & his son Prativindhya is believed to be younger than Abhimanyu ( 16 years ) . In one side there are pandavas who were in 90s in war & their sons were all younger than Abhimanyu. And on other side abhimanyu became father at a very young age of 16 but Pandavas became father at their late 70s . Why their is so much difference.  Can you please throw some light ?

Comment: @RanaPriyanshuSinh, already explained in last comment. they can decide WHEN to have children. You are biologically capable of having a child when you are 16, as well as 60.